# Is there any new version of Weinre?

Tags: console, google-chrome-devtools, weinre

I am searching for a similar project or a new version of Weinre that has a latest dev tools console. I need timeline and profiling but the current version of Weinre does not have a lot of tools.

So, is there any new version of Weinre?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, there isn't a version of weinre with profiling, because that's something weinre just can't do.

If you're not aware, there are modern versions of browser debugging tools available for various mobile platforms.  I've placed some links to them here:
http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/

Comment: thanks for the answer. I can't find them. Can you please list them here? I only find Weinre. What am I missing?

Comment: sorry, the links in the yellow box at the top of the page, that start with the heading "Do you need to use weinre?" - http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre-docs/latest/